# Assign Item ID before submit with multiple users

Tags: sql, asp.net, web

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms web application. Users can submit new requests through the system. When a user open a request form it should display the request number in the request interface.

request number is similar to the request number in the database which is a auto increment field in the database starting from 1. So when a user open a new request form, it checks for the max request number in the database table and add +1 to the number and display it as the request id for the new request. This method was successful until few users were using it.

But when the number of users increased I faced this problem. When two users trying to add a new request at the same time they both receive the same request number. So now I need to handle this issue. What is the best approach to handle this issue? Any suggestions and clues are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the request number is the primary key, you can set auto increment for that property and the db will handle it for you automatically.

Comment: But I need to display the request number on the new request form which is not yet submitted. And I the request number is primary key and already set to auto increment.

Comment: There will be no good solution to this problem.  You can do things like insert the record to reserve the next number from the identity (auto increment) column, but then you might be violating other constraints on the table.  Best case, you end up with many empty records due to users starting the process but not completing it.  You could then run a scheduled clean up task to remove those records.

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades Thank you very much for the comment! Is there any better I could achieve this kind of functionality? (Display the request number before they submit it?)

Comment: I have ran across this issue before where they want the order number before submitting the order so they can have it when discussing with the customer.  But unless you reserve that number during the process, you can't guarantee it.  And if you reserve it, then you end up with blank rows.  Blank rows and skipped ID numbers may not be the worst thing in the world; pretty easy to clean that up with a scheduled task.  If request numbers can be skipped (due to not finishing request) then just go with reserving the number and a nightly cleanup routine.

Comment: Depending on your specific database, you might be able to use [Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) instead of an Identity column.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sequence will prevent blank rows and prevent you from having to run a clean up routine.  Good advice.  You will still get skipped numbers if users do not finish the request.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you for your advice. Will use that for my solution. Thanks for the help. :)